# Ошибки в быстрой сортировке Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, сортировка, qsort

Пробовала несколько вариаций быстрой сортировки для массива случайных чисел чисел.

Объявляю массив:

```
n = 10
my_array = []
for i in range(n):
    my_array.append(randint(1, 2000))
```

Первая вариация сортировки:

```
def my_quick(array):
    chosen = array[0]
    low = [elem for elem in array[1:] if elem <= chosen]
    high = [elem for elem in array[1:] if elem > chosen]
    return my_quick(low) + [chosen] + my_quick(high)
```

Вторая:

```
def my_quick(array):
    low = []
    middle = []
    high = []
    chosen = my_array[0]
    for elem in array:
        if elem < chosen:
            low.append(elem)
        elif elem > chosen:
            high.append(elem)
        else:
            middle.append(elem)
    return my_quick(low)+middle+my_quick(high)
```

Ошибки (одинаковые для 2 реализаций):
1. При вызове функции.
2. 3 раза выводит ошибку в последней строчке сортировок.
3. array[0] (IndexError: list index out of range)

Хоть убей не понимаю в чём дело и как исправить, в многих источниках аналогичный код

Answer (score 2):

В коде нет условия останова рекурсии - когда список состоит из одного элемента или пуст - он отсортирован, надо сразу вернуться.

Иначе происходит обращение к несуществующим индексам (о чём свидетельствует текст ошибки)

Comment: Тоже об этом думала, спасибо)
А как это остановку в данном случае задать?

Comment: `if len(array) <= 1:    return array`